# scala boolean variables need to change dynamicly

Tags: scala, boolean

I have this method that I need to evaluate an expression based on these Boolean values:

```
var Ma, Co, Ar, Le, St, Ri: Boolean = false
def Logic: Boolean =
  (Ma  &  (!Ma  |  Co)  &  (!Ma  |  Ar)  &  (!Co  |  Ma)  &  
      (!Ar  |  Ma)  &  (!Ar  |  Le  |  St |  Ri))
```

In `main()` method I have:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {   
  val ls: List[String] = List("Ma", "Co", "Ar")
  //now I need to change the value of Ma, Co and Ar variables to "true"??
}
```

Is there a general way that may help to change the value of only these Boolean variables to `true` that are found in this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without reflection, I think. But if you keep the name->value mapping in a map, you can do something like this:

```
val v =  scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Boolean]("Ma" -> false, "Co"-> false, "Ar" -> false, "Le" -> false, "St" -> false, "Ri" -> false)
    //> v  : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Boolean] = Map(Ar -> false, Le -> f
    //| alse, Co -> false, Ma -> false, St -> false, Ri -> false)
def Logic:Boolean = (v("Ma")  &  (!v("Ma")  | v("Co"))  &  (!v("Ma")  |  v("Ar"))  &  (!v("Co")  | v("Ma"))  &
        (!v("Ar")  |  v("Ma"))  &  (!v("Ar")  |  v("Le")  |  v("St") |  v("Ri")))
    //> Logic: => Boolean

val ls: List[String] = List("Ma", "Co", "Ar")     //> ls  : List[String] = List(Ma, Co, Ar)
v("Ma")                                           //> res0: Boolean = false
ls.foreach(v(_) = true)
v("Ma")                                           //> res1: Boolean = true
Logic                                             //> res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I am already using your suggestion, and @Ashalynd 's one. They look functional, but I have to understand now what `v(..)` means and I didn't know when to use it :(

Comment: v is just a Map, and holds String keys and corresponding Boolean valuer. `v(foo)` is shorthand for `v.apply(foo)`, and takes the String foo, looks up the corresponding value, and returns it @Ashalynd's solution extends this idea to have a Map with a default value of `false` so you only have to set specific names to true. Although convenient, I don't like this as it means if you misspell a parameter name, it will return false when you look it up, which may be difficult to track down. In my version, using an unknown name would be a (runtime) error

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`Enumeration`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala/Enumeration.html), and use its `ValueSet` to store your true values instead of individual `var`s. This lets you refer to them by `String` name:

```scala
object MyBoolValue extends Enumeration {
  type MyBoolValue = Value
  val Ma, Co, Ar, Le, St, Ri = Value
}
class MyBoolValueContext {
  var trueValues = MyBoolValue.ValueSet.empty
  def isTrue(v: MyBoolValue) = trueValues contains v
  def apply(v: MyBoolValue) = isTrue(v)
}
```

So then you can do:

```scala
import MyBoolValue._
val c = new MyBoolValueContext
c(Ma)
c.trueValues += Le
c.trueValues -= St

def logic: Boolean = (c(Ma) &
                      (!c(Ma) | c(Co)) &
                      (!c(Ma) | c(Ar)) &
                      (!c(Co) | c(Ma)) &
                      (!c(Ar) | c(Ma)) &
                      (!c(Ar) | c(Le) | c(St) | c(Ri)))
```

And you can use `withName` to handle `String` input:

```scala
c.trueValues ++= List("Ar", "Le", "St").map(MyBoolValue.withName)
```

You can get a little fancier by making the context implicit:

```scala
implicit case class ResolveMyBoolValue(self: MyBoolValue) extends AnyVal {
  def get(implicit context: MyBoolValueContext): Boolean = context.isTrue(self)
}

implicit val context = new MyBoolValueContext

val result = Ar.get | !St.get
```

Or use an implicit conversion, though this could cause some confusion if misused:

```scala
implicit def resolveMyBoolValue(v: MyBoolValue)
                               (implicit context: MyBoolValueContext) = {
  context.isTrue(v)
}

val result: Boolean = Le
```

Comment: I personally think this one's a bit overkill, but it's neat, so +1 anyway. It seems to be coming fairly close to implementing your own Boolean type (or "set of Booleans" type)

Comment: I really appreciate your reply @Dan Getz...but for me, as a kind of beginner in Scala, this is of a "heavy caliber":)

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do it:

```
def Logic(params:List[String]) = {
 val p = params.map(par => (par, true)).toMap.withDefaultValue(false)
 (
    p("Ma")  &  (
        !p("Ma")  |  p("Co")
    )  &  (
        !p("Ma")  |  p("Ar")
    )  &  (
        !p("Co")  |  p("Ma")
    )  & (
        !p("Ar")  |  p("Ma")
    )  &  (
        !p("Ar")  |  p("Le")  |  p("St") |  p("Ri")
    )
  )
}

scala> Logic(List("Ma","Co","Ar"))
res0: Boolean = false
scala> Logic(List("Ma","Co","Ar","Le"))
res1: Boolean = true
```